# Hover state not working on mobile on tap

Tags: html, css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, hover

I'm trying to figure out how I can make the hover state work when you tap a box on mobile. I know that you are not able to use `:hover` on mobile. I have tried using `:active` also, but still it doesnt work.

You can check out the issue under  "Projects currently under development" section [here](http://www.fantasylab.no/comingsoon/). You will have to test it on a mobile device.

Here is the current code I am using for the boxes:

**HTML**

```
<section id="portfolio-soon" class="bg-light-gray">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Projects currently under development</h2>
                <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">These projects are currently being designed and developed.</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <div class="portfolio-link" >
                    <div class="portfolio-hover orange-boxfit">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                            Coming Soon
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/portfolio/boxfit.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-caption">
                    <h4>BoxFit</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Web Design, Development &amp; Web Hosting</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#portfolio-soon .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover {
  background: rgba(124,44,227, 0.9);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

#portfolio-soon .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NohmanJ: I have tried to add :active state and it works well. User need to click to the item in mobile to see the overlay. Did you use the same code as below ?
Because it's popular approach to set the same style for both :hover and :active If you want to archive your code in mobile.

```
#portfolio-soon .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover:hover, #portfolio-soon .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover:active {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I added that code now. I was testing on iPhone. On iPhone it's not working, however on Android it's working fine.

Comment: I made a test on iPhone actually and it worked :D 
Anyway please be noted that it will only show "clearly" for Projects currently under development because when you tap in, it will reveal the overlay only. 
For Featured Projects, normally once hover it will reveal the overlay and once click It will open the modal. So on the mobile, It will first reveal the overlay as a flash then show the modal right after you tapping. It's something that we cannot make the same in both desktop and mobile.